# How to view active database in hive terminal?

Tags: hive, terminal, hiveql

Is there is any way to see in which database we are working with in hive terminal. while working in hive using webGUI(hue) there is a list of database from where we can select the database(which will be active database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can. for that we have to set the properties in hive terminal.

> SET hive.cli.print.current.db = true;